# Increase vertical distance between chapter title and chapter preamble (Koma Script)

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script, scrbook

I'm using Koma Script's `scrbook` for a document. I would like to insert some text above chapter headings, which can be done like this:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble[o]{Text above chapter title}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to increase the vertical distance (by let's say `20\baselineskip`) between `Text above chapter title` and `Chapter title`. How could I do this?

I know that the command `\chapterheadstartvskip` exists, but it doesn't do what I want:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{20\baselineskip}}   

\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble[o]{Text above chapter title}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\end{document}
```

Instead of having this output:

```
20\baselineskip
Text above chapter title
Chapter title
```

I would like this output:

```
Text above chapter title
20\baselineskip
Chapter title
```

`Text above chapter title` should stay on the upper part of the page and not move down.

By the way, I know that this doesn't make much sense from a typographical point of view, but in my use case, it is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chapter preamble is inserted at the bottom of the space above the chapter title. So if your preamble is one line and there should be a space of 20\baselineskip you can adjust the space above the chapter using

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-21\baselineskip]{chapter}
```

Then you can use a `\parbox` with the same height, outer alignment `b`ottom and inner alignment `t`op.

```
\setchapterpreamble[o]{%
  \parbox[b][21\baselineskip][t]{\linewidth}{%
    \strut Text above chapter title}}
\chapter{Chapter title}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-21\baselineskip]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble[o]{%
  \parbox[b][21\baselineskip][t]{\linewidth}{%
    \strut Text above chapter title}}
\chapter{Chapter title}
Normal text
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-21\baselineskip]{chapter}
\newcommand\mychapterpreamble[1]{%
  \parbox[b][21\baselineskip][t]{\linewidth}{\strut\ignorespaces#1}}
\begin{document}
\setchapterpreamble[o]{\mychapterpreamble{  Text above chapter title}}
\chapter{Chapter title}
Normal text
\end{document}
```

or only local for one chapter

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
{
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-21\baselineskip]{chapter}
  \setchapterpreamble[o]{%
    \parbox[b][21\baselineskip][t]{\linewidth}{%
    \strut Text above chapter title}}
  \chapter{Chapter title}
}
\chapter{Second chapter title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and explication. Is is working perfectly well in my document. Just a small remark: I noticed that there is a \ missing before `baselineskip` in "or only local for one chapter".

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Now I have inserted the missing backslash.